# NodeJS + ExpressJS - how to point my domain name to port 3000?

Tags: node.js, linux, express

In my live server I have my expressjs app running at

```
http://122.22.11.22:3000
```

But how can I use a **domain name** or **sub domain name** instead? for instace:

```
http://my-express.com
```

or

```
http://exress.mymastersite.com
```

I use express-generator to create my express skeleton btw. And I am on Linux Arch.

Any ideas?

Inside bin/www I have this code below generated by the express-generator automatically by default:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('mongoose-iot:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

....
....
....
```

Answer (score 4):

What you want to do is called virtualhosting,
You can use nginx to do it

Make your express listens only on localhost :
`server.listen(3000, 'localhost');`

And setup your ngnix as this :

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name express.your-domain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    } }
```

You can add as many virtualhost as you want.

Comment: any alternative to `ngnix`? I have a problem installing it on my localhost ubuntu so i dare not install it in my live server arch linux.

Comment: apache or haproxy can do it as well.
Or you can try https://github.com/expressjs/vhost directly in nodejs.