# Deploy Express Backend To Local Server

Tags: node.js, express

I want to turn my express backend from http://localhost:3000/ to something like http://localhost/backend, how should I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NodeJS + ExpressJS - how to point my domain name to port 3000?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39742904/nodejs-expressjs-how-to-point-my-domain-name-to-port-3000)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [server](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server) block of `nginx`.

`nginx.conf`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
    }
}
```

`app.ts`:

```
import express from 'express';

const app = express();

app.get('/backend', (req, res) => {
  res.sendStatus(200);
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('server started at port 3000'));
```

Test:

```sh
^ curl http://localhost/backend               

OK%
```